# livepatch apparmor="DENIED"?

Tags: networking, apparmor, canonical-livepatch

I've just installed canonical-livepatch on Ubuntu Server 16.04.6 LTS and when I try to register the machine I get this on the enable command:

```
2019/10/20 11:33:55 error executing enable: cannot enable machine: cannot send request: Post https://livepatch.canonical.com/api/machine-tokens: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup "http: no such host
```

And this in syslog:

```
Oct 20 11:27:18 lorina canonical-livepatch[3287]: during refresh: cannot check: No machine-token. Please run 'canonical-livepatch enable'!
Oct 20 11:27:29 lorina kernel: [701248.639128] audit: type=1400 audit(1571567249.885:210): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch" name="/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/hpage_pmd_size" pid=3420 comm="canonical-livep" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Oct 20 11:29:04 lorina kernel: [701343.340206] audit: type=1400 audit(1571567344.591:211): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch" name="/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/hpage_pmd_size" pid=3552 comm="canonical-livep" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

If I run `host livepatch.canonical.com` it resolves fine. The proxy also allows the http request OK, and the error still happens when I disable the firewall.

Does anyone know where to start on this?

Comment: I'm getting tons of these canonical snap livepatch errors in dmesg as well on 18.04.3 and am ready to see this improved

Comment: Hi Tommy, I found this bug and confirmed that I have the same there https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-livepatch-client/+bug/1847319 - But seeing that many users have these warnings I'd not expect this to be related to your failure to enable the machine.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt Thanks for that, although I'm getting a 404 on that URL. But if it's the case that the warnings aren't related to livepatch, I'm not sure what to do to get livepatch working.

Comment: Yes it was moved to snapcraft or snapd I think. The edge channel already has a fix for the apparmor warnings. You can yourself report a bug there for your case and hope they can help (the more details the more likely). => https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-livepatch-client/+filebug

Comment: FTR: this is a working bug link http://pad.lv/1847319

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt Thanks - I filed a bug report.